# How to Repeat (Continuse) TileMap in Cocos 2d?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I made a game using cocos 2d.

I made a Tile based map, in which I want to repeat the map when it is complete.

My problem is in the game, the map moves completely for the first time but I want to continues repeat it.

I am using the following code to move the map.

```
-(void) moveMap
{
    // Create the actions   
    id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:10.0 position:ccp(-1,(-self.tileMap.contentSize.height))];
    id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setViewpointCenter:)];
    [self.tileMap runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
}
```

This works properly and the map moves downward till map height, after that the map will disappear. Now I want to continue repeating the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate your tile map into two smaller tile maps and put them one next to each other.

Then in your update method check their positions and when first one goes offscreen, move it after second one. When second one goes offscreen, move it after first one.

Comment: Yeah that's the easiest way to do it.

Comment: i use one map multiple time after it complete i repeat that map again...Thanks for idea...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single map that's larger that the screen, then every 32px in any given direction, shift the map back 32px. This is useful for infinite maps. It requires one a single object and texture, plus is works both for vertical and horizontal motion. It can be a pain to time correctly, but so can the multiple map scenario.

(I upvoted fichek's answer because it's the most common.)

Comment: my object move accordingly Horizontally only. So i repeat my map vertically as suggest by fichek.Thank for your answer